# Ruby, define_method, Singletons, Inheritance

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaprogramming

I got a Singleton Class like

```
module Database
  class Table
    include Singleton
    # ...
  end
end
```

And in this Class I'm using in a method the `define_method`-method and get:

```
/home/jrn/Development/RocketRuby/lib/modules/database.rb:184:in `block in register_methods': undefined method `define_method' for #<Accounting::UsersTable:0x00000001f103c8> (NoMethodError)
```

(As you can see, the Class `Table` has been inherited by a Class called `UsersTable` in the Module `Accounting`)

What might gone wrong? What are typical mistakes when working with `define_methods` and `Singleton`?

Yours, Joern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
class Table
  include Singleton

  def register_methods
    self.class.send(:define_method, :hello) { puts "Hello!" }
  end


  # or ...

  def register_methods
    define_singleton_method(:hello) { puts "Hello!" }
  end
```

Comment: not exactly, but I tried an almost same ugly workaround. thanks, I may try your variation

Comment: thank god! your solution just worked! I also went over `self.class`, but I tried `self.class.define_method`, which didn't work, on the other hand `self.class.send(:define_method, ...) {}` worked well!